# "Failed Invalid File provided for module import! Try Again."

Tags: php, zip, vtiger, vtigercrm

I've downloaded an Example module `HelloWorld` from forum `Vtiger CRM` , import  it in module designer and have modified it and export it.

When i try to install my new module in file `Zip`  i see the below message! and I using `Vtiger CRM` in my localhost

`"Failed Invalid File provided for module import! Try Again."`

Whats the problem?

I Using `Vtigercrm version 6.5.0`

please!. tell me that how to fix problem.

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, what is a `Module Designer`? Is that specific to VTiger CRM? For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

module folder structure should be like this.

you need to select these three and create zip . Do not zip the folder containing these files.

second thing languages folder is must

example module : requirements

modules/

```
   Requirements/

       Requirements.php
```

languages/

```
en_us/

    Requirements.php
```

manifest.xml

Comment: Hello @lajeesh k , i have an example module HelloWorld and structure in the module is here.  - manifest.xml
- modules/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.php
- modules/HelloWorld/views/List.php
- languages/en_us/HelloWorld.php
- templates/List.tpl . So could you tell me how to create the zip for exactly. Regards.

Comment: you may be putting all these files in a folder and create zip from that. Don't do like that. select mainfest.xml file , modules, languages, templates folder and choose create zip. means select these 4 items and create zip

Comment: I did follow your guide but it still fail. Can you give me the exact way to make up a module and give module out. Best Regards

Comment: please share the module zip you have created and I will see

Comment: I have created a example module "HelloWorld" in netbeans IDE 8.2 . I will share you this source code in zip file. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YYPeMZBazpZgYLD5TEOGG39Ay9EvDldK) Can you give me the exact way to make up a module and give module out. Best Regard.

Answer (score 1):

Zip fie structure is proper for your provided link. Please check below path "modules/HelloWorld/views/List.php" in zip. "view" folder needs to be renamed as "views".

I tried with that and it worked and imported successfully.